# Spring MVC не находит controller (404 error)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, servlet

Создал `Spring MVC` проект, который при запросе на `localhost:port/search` должен перебрасывать на сайт гугла. Вместо этого выдается ошибка 404. Не могу понять, в чем дело? Использую java конфиг, без web.xml.

```
package com.example.config;

public class MainAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = 
                  new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
            
                root.register(WebApplicationContextConfig.class);
            
                servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));
     
                ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet = 
                  servletContext.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(root));
                appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
                appServlet.addMapping("/");
    
    }

}

package com.example.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class WebApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean=new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
          bean.setPrefix("/");
          bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Вот сам контроллер. При переходе на `/search` в консоль должно выводиться сообщение `"logging message from controller"`, но этого не происходит. Spring не распознает данный контроллер

```
package com.example.controller;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String getIndexPage(Model model) {
        System.out.println("logging message from controller");
        return "redirect:http://google.com";
    }
}
```

структура проекта:

[image: структура папок]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. В `properties/deployment assembly` для `maven dependencies` не был задан `deploy path`. Присвоил ему значение `WEB-INF/lib` и все заработало